# How do you get a JS DOM/JQuery Object for Form Tag in form_remote_tag's :complete callback?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, callback, prototypejs

In Rails 2.3.3, I want to do something like:

```
<% form_remote_tag :url => "/some/path/", :loading => "loadingFunction(this)", :complete => "completeFunction(this,request)" do %>
```

Basically, I want to be able to pass that specific form tag to the :complete or :loading callback functions (in a RELATIVE way - I don't want to use an ID - I want to be able to get the  tag that the :complete call corresponds to as a natural result of the :complete call being for the form tag**).

See [Rails documentation for form_remote_tag](http://www.railsbrain.com/api/rails-2.2.2/doc/index.html?a=M002043&name=form_remote_tag).  In particular, Rails generates code like the following for the onsubmit event: new Ajax.Request('/some/path/', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, onComplete:function(request){completeFunction(this,request)}, onLoading:function(request){loadingFunction(this)}, parameters:Form.serialize(this)}); return false;" .  Note how the function calls are wrapped within function(request){} which is inside new Ajax.Request().

So, "this", "jQuery(this)", "jQuery(this).closest('.someParentElementOfTheForm')" etc. don't work.

---

**I am doing this because:
I'm rendering an arbitrary number of "form_remote_tag"s with when the page is loaded, and the user can trigger events that cause arbitrarily more "form_remote_tag"s to appear (with similar content in each form, but the amount of elements in each form is also arbitrary).  If I have one form_remote_tag in the entire page, there are a few main problems:

- The user will only be editing one section of the page (which in my current design corresponds to one form), but all of the form elements' data in the page will have to be sent in the request
- It would require some sort of messy way to keep track of forms and their elements, giving them IDs such as: 'form-12','form-12-paramfield-13' etc.
- It makes it very difficult to allow: the user to submit one form, and while that form is loading via AJAX, submit other forms (including the possibility of triggering an event that causes a new form to appear and then submitting that form), because of issues with keeping track of where to put the response data for each request

Comment: what you did to make this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the by passing below  callbacks in html options like

:html => { :loading => "#{remotefunction(options)}; return false;" }
    or 
:html => { :onloading => "#{remotefunction(options)}; return false;" }

The callbacks that may be specified are (in order):

```
:loading:   Called when the remote document is being loaded with data by the browser.
:loaded:    Called when the browser has finished loading the remote document.
:interactive:   Called when the user can interact with the remote document, even though it has not finished loading.
:success:   Called when the XMLHttpRequest is completed, and the HTTP status code is in the 2XX range.
:failure:   Called when the XMLHttpRequest is completed, and the HTTP status code is not in the 2XX range.
:complete:  Called when the XMLHttpRequest is complete (fires after success/failure if they are present).
```

You can further refine :success and :failure by adding additional callbacks for specific status codes.

Recently I have achieved to overiride onsubmit in one my remote forms as below

```
 <% options = {:url => {:action =>"test", :id => 1}, :with =>"Form.serialize('test_form')" }%>
 <% form_remote_tag :html=>{ :onsubmit =>"#{remote_function(options)}; return false" } do %>
```